# Background size and position

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form [in my page](http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/index3.html) and i am trying to increase the size of the background and change its position to no avail.

CSS:

```
.w2_ajax_contact_form {
width: 30%;
margin: auto;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
background-position: 0% 20%;
}
```

I tried a few ways like:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) center center;
```

and

```
background-position: 10px;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: All that I see is a solid color with `80%` opacity for the background, so there is nothing to change the size of or shift.

Comment: A solid background color is uniform across an entire box so you can't position it. You need to position the element instead, e.g. by using margins.

Comment: Yeah thats what i needed to actually move, the bg color, but if its not possible then ill move the element instead, just wanted to know if there is an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-position` is meant to position a background **image**, not a background color. It is mostly used for working with sprites. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but i think you may just want to add some padding to your form.

Comment: yup i commented above, i was trying to move the color...guess i cant..thanx anyways..ill accept it once it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move the color. It works only with images. try to increase the `height`, `width` or add some kind of `padding` to the box